# Eclipse RCP 3.7 programmatically adding detached views to existing window

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I currently have 2 detached windows but would like to have 1 window with the two detached views as tabs. Is there a way to programmatically do this? I'm working with Eclipse RCP 3.7

Comment: Eclipse 3.7 is now 9 years and 16 releases old. There were very large changes in  window handling for Eclipse 4 so most recent answers you may find will not apply.

Comment: @greg-449 I know, I realised while searching for answers. I hope that maybe someone out there is stuck in a company still using old tech like I am who may have the answers I seek :)